# Discarding a comment switches to answers in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

1. Start writing a comment
2. Swipe the right edge to the left to reveal the Discard button
3. **The view is changed from question to answers!**
4. Switch back to the question
5. Now you can discard the comment

The bug is that swiping the right edge serves two incompatible purposes

[image]

<sup>SE 0.1.47, iOS 7.1</sup>

Comment: Needz moar frame rate.

Comment: You're tellin me! One. Screenshot. At a time! At least there are freehand red circles?

Comment: Yep.  Self-morphizing freehand circles.

Comment: Tough crowd. ;)

Comment: Wow, excellent find. I'll be taking a look at this.

Comment: @arie, I should say I like the idea of swiping between questions and answers and would hate to lose that. Take a look at what the Reeder app does. You don't need to swipe from the edge; can swipe from anywhere.

Comment: @mhlester thanks for the suggestion, but swiping from anywhere creates issues, because we have other swipe-enabled elements, such as code views.

Comment: good call; no worries. thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be **fixed in version 0.1.48**